# Curly brackets in command input using expect language

Tags: expect

I am attempting to automate the change of switch configurations on multiple cisco switches. I get all the way to the config section and when the config.txt variable is sent, the output has curly brackets at the end and is not a valid command. Here is the output and below that I will post the code.
All I am trying to do is login to my switch and run the following command
configure replace flash:/thenameofconfig
The script will loop through multiple switches in the device list and apply the correct config based o

IL-test-SW1#configure replace flash:/il-test-sw2-confg} {}

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Set up various other variables here ($user, $password)
set username user
set password user
set enablepassword user

# Log results
#log_file -a ~/results.log
log_file -a /tmp/results.log







# Get the list of hosts, one per line #####
set f [open "device-list.txt"]
set hostname [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Get the commands to run, one per line
set f [open "configs.txt"]
set configs [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Iterate over the hosts
foreach host $hostname {
# Don't check keys
 spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username\@$hostname
#    spawn ssh $user@host
#    expect "password:"
#    send "$password\r"
# Allow this script to handle ssh connection issues
 expect {
 timeout { send_user "\nTimeout Exceeded - Check Host\n"; exit 1 }
 eof { send_user "\nSSH Connection To $hostname Failed\n"; exit 1 }
 "*#" {}
 "*assword:" {
 send "$password\n"
 }
 }

# If we're not already in enable mode, get us there
 expect {
 default { send_user "\nEnable Mode Failed - Check Password\n"; exit 1 }
 "*#" {}
 "*>" {
 send "enable\n"
 expect "*assword"
 send "$enablepassword\n"
 expect "*#"
 }
 }

# Let's go to configure mode
 send "conf t\n"
expect "(config)#"
send "shell processing full\n"
expect "(config)#"
send "end\n"
expect "*#"

#Iterate over the commands
foreach config $configs {
expect "*#" 
send "$configs\n" 
expect "\[no]:"
send "y\n"  
expect "*#"
}    
     # Tidy up
#    expect "*#"
#    send "exit\r"
#    expect eof
#    close
send "exit\n"
 expect ":~\$"
 exit

}
```

Cannot seem to get rid of the {} at the end of the configure replace command.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Was the following line

set hostname [split [read $f] "\n"]

Needs to be:
set hostname [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]